# Problem With Local Area Connection MONGO DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, flutter

I am developing an application that used mongo db as the database - server.
the server resides on my personal machine , and wanted my friend to be able to access it.
I am using an ethernet cable to connect to my friends machine.
changed mongodb.cfg file and added his IP address and restarted the service which work fine on my local machine.
but when ever he tries to connect he get an error stating "target-machine-actively-refused-it on 192.168.2.4:2707
using the command " mongo --host 192.168.2.4:2707
Have checked the port and all seems to be fine and disabled firewall. but nothing seems to work

he can ping my address , but when it comes to the access of db it refuses. any help please

- tried netstat on my machines
- deliberately closed my firewall
  -changed the cross over cable , but still he can only ping my machine

Comment: Please mention the OS you are using.

Answer (score 0):

To allow access from specific IP you can set `bindIp` property.

```
net:
  port: 27017 // or any other custom port
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1,192.168.0.10,192.168.0.12
```

https://gist.github.com/royz/46397fe4ee25dc14418b41821ee45335